# gcloud API shutdown and start-up

Tags: cloud, startup, shutdown, gcloud

Is there an Google API that allows me auto  shutdown and startup my instance at a certain time ? How do I go about doing this ?

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Compute Engine offers two methods to [start](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/start)
and [stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/stop) instances but it doesn't provide a way to call them at a certain time.

A workaround would be using cron either under [a Linux box](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) or [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) which is used to schedule jobs and it seems to fit your needs.